# iPhone: how to get IPA onto non jailbroken iPhone without iTunes and without e-mail?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipa

my friend borrowed me his (non jailbroken) iphone 4s to test my iphone application. How can I get the IPA onto his iphone without syncing with itunes? (IPA is created with Flash, so i can't use XCode). I know there are some over the air services but they require to open e-mails with the e-mail application on the phone. I don't want to open his e-mails, so, is there another way to get the IPA onto it?

Comment: The over-the-air services don't require email, they just use that since it is easier than typing a weird link into Safari. But you can totally just type those URLs into Safari.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Testflight http://testflightapp.com
It gives you a short url after uploading a build which you can install the IPA from there.

Don't forget to add the device UDID to the certificates.

Comment: PS. this is iOS 8 only

Answer (score 3):

OTA (over the air) is the way to go if you don't want to use TestFlightApp.

Distribute the app via ad-hoc distribution, and store the app on a web server. You can then directly download the app from the web server onto your iPhone by calling the appropriate url in Safari.

Here is a guide on how to do this:

http://iosdevelopertips.com/xcode/distribute-ad-hoc-applications-over-the-air-ota.html

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at TestFlightApp. You can create a new (or use an existing), web-based email address and use that to register your friend's device with the your TestFlightApp account.